# How to return all/multiple tokens owned by an account?

Tags: tokens, api

How do you return the balance of multiple tokens for an account in a single call?

I'm using `get_currency_balance` to return the balance of a single token:

`POST https://eos.greymass.com/v1/chain/get_currency_balance`

```
{
    "code": "eosio.token",
    "account": "b1",
    "symbol": "EOS"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native single endpoint to return all Token-Balances for a single account. You would need to do one request per token-contract.

[Dfuse](https://docs.dfuse.eosnation.io/eosio/public-apis/reference/graphql-api/) offers a GraphQl-Query (accountBalances) to query multiple balances at once but dfuse comes with a rate-limit.